# Using solr search for mysql database table

Tags: mysql, database, search, solr

I am new to solr and trying to use it to index my database "zend" and table "users". Below is the code of data-config.xml that is located at /solr/example/solr/conf/ folder

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/zend" 
              user="root" 
              password=""/>
    <document>
        <entity name="id" query="select id,first_name,last_name from users">
            <field column="id" name="solr_id"/>
            <field column="first_name" name="solr_first_name"/>
            <field column="last_name" name="solr_last_name"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Below code I put in solrconfig.xml located at /solr/example/solr/conf folder

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

And these fields I added in schema.xml of /solr/example/solr/conf folder

```
<field name="solr_id" type="genericID" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="solr_first_name" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="solr_last_name" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

After making these changes I run `java -jar start.jar`

When I hit the full import command from browser like

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

Then I get the error:

> HTTP ERROR: 500
>       Severe errors in solr configuration.
>       Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.
>       If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:
>        <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>
>       in null

Please advise.

Comment: Accept answers that help and start building your reputation and rating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an configuration error at your config - files.
That could be for example an syntax error, missing end-tag or something like that.
Your solution is written at your question:

```
Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.
```

So please check the output of your java-container.... probably the output of the java -jar command or the logfiles generated by java and/or the start.jar
..and post the output here

Comment: I am able to index the data now but the issue is no result is coming up after searching anything. I am using the way described at http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/wiki/ExampleUsage       Please advice

Comment: first of all you should check, if your solr is running correctly. Use `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin` for that. Check `http://phoenixdb01t:8080/solr/rss/admin/stats.jsp` if all documents are indexed and run an search on `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin`

Comment: Issue was, solr was comparing the key as exact word match that i was providing in my search. But when i changed the type "text" from "textgen" then it started searching like a "LIKE" operator in mysql. So now this issue is resolved. Many thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Witch version of Solr are you using? In never versions DIH is not in solr.war, but have to be loaded externally: [SOLR-2365: DIH should not be in the Solr war](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2365)

Comment: This issue has already been fixed (last week). search result is coming now. Earlier solr was searching exact word whatever i was providing but after changing the type in schema.xml for those fields to "text", it started working fine. Buy anyways thanks for your concern. BTW I AM USING SOLR 1.4.1